# when move to one Activity to map view activity it crashing

Tags: android

I created two activities First Activity contains a button and another Activity contains Google map view  when clicked to the button i want to move to the google mapview Activity but Application is crashing .also included the all permissions and map view in XML page and intent  and extend Map View and uses-library in manifest but still cant work

Comment: if you provide your crash catlog could help people figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Is your second activity is extended from MapActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the map view activity to the Android Manifext.xml/Application/Application Nodes?